# Load image with libgdx

Tags: java, image, libgdx

I am trying to load two images on the java application built by libgdx library. I loaded the background image however, I could not load the other images on to the screen if I am not set the position of the images to (0,0).
For example;
I set the position of the image to 0,0 and there is no problem. However, when I set the position of the image to 20, 0, it cannot be seen.

```
batch.draw(Assets.coinRegion, position.x, position.y, 1, 1)
```

I am trying to draw the image with the above code.

Thank you.

Edit:

```
obstacle = loadTexture("data/obstacle.png"); 
obstacleRegion = new TextureRegion(obstacle, 0, 0, 64, 64);
world.obstacle.position.x += 0.001; 
batch.draw(Assets.obstacleRegion,
world.obstacle.position.x, world.obstacle.position.y, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The TextureRegion class describes a rectangle inside a texture and is useful for drawing only a portion of the texture.

```
private TextureRegion region;
...
texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("image.png"));
region = new TextureRegion(texture, 20, 20, 50, 50);
//if you have 2 images in image.png add new region and specify rectangular:
//region2 = new TextureRegion(texture, 70, 0, 100, 100);
...
batch.begin();
batch.draw(region, 10, 10);
batch.end();
```

Here the 20, 20, 50, 50 describes the portion of the texture, which is then drawn at 10,10. The same can be achieved by passing the Texture and other parameters to SpriteBatch, but TextureRegion makes it convenient to have a single object that describes both.

SpriteBatch has many methods for drawing a texture region

source: [source](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SpriteBatch#TextureRegion)

if you have 2 images in 1 then use several "region" variables.. (region1 = new ... and region2 = new...), otherwise load 2 files and do the same what written in documentation.

Comment: In my status, I have two seperate images, one of them is 64x64 and the other one is 32x32. I create two TextureRegion and try to draw them as I wrote in my question. With the 0, 0 position they are fine otherwise not. Edit: In my program I am trying to get the image like region = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 64, 64).

Comment: `obstacle = loadTexture("data/obstacle.png");
  obstacleRegion = new TextureRegion(obstacle, 0, 0, 64, 64);world.obstacle.position.x += 0.001;
  batch.draw(Assets.obstacleRegion, world.obstacle.position.x, 
       world.obstacle.position.y, 1, 1);` if i set the world.obstacle.position.x and position.y to 0,0 it is fine otherwise not. And is this code ok. Since it is the comment area i could not post more.

Comment: @Tekinalp please edit your question to include the code.  See the StackOverflow FAQ for more details on updating and editing your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: From libgdx javadoc (class SpriteBatch): `draw(TextureRegion region, float x, float y, float width, float height)`
          "Draws a rectangle with the bottom left corner at x,y and stretching the region to cover the given width and height." ---> But you set width and height 1px and that's why you don't see your image.

Comment: I found the problem. It is about the camera position.Thank you for your answer.